# passing array value using closure

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

Whats the best way of getting multiple local arrays from another function.  I am doing something similar to this.  And as far as the variable names attached to a function, "arr1=f1()", do these need to be declared as local ,"var arr1=f1()".

```
<script>

    function ArrValues(arr){
        var array=arr;
        function f1(){
            var ID=[];
            ID=['grapes','peaches','plums'];
            return ID
        };
        function f2(){
            var Nam=[]; 
            Nam=['car','motorcycle','tree'];
            return Nam
        };
        function f3(){
            var Num=[]; 
            Num=['200','1000','350'];
            return Num
        };

        if(array=='one' || array=='all'){ arr1=f1()};
        if(array=='two' || array=='all'){ var arr2=f2()};
        if(array=='three' || array=='all'){ var arr3=f3()};

        gotIt(arr1,arr2,arr3)
    }

    function gotIt(arr1,arr2,arr3){
        alert(arr1);
        alert(arr2);
        alert(arr3);
    }

</script>

<div id="one" onclick="ArrValues(this.id)">one</div>
<div id="two" onclick="ArrValues(this.id)">two</div>
<div id="three"onclick="ArrValues(this.id)">three</div>
<div id="all"onclick="ArrValues(this.id)">all</div>
```

Comment: Always use `var` at the top of the scope, or at least *in a logical location* (e.g. at the top of a `for`, bearing in mind that it is hoisted anyway). It's hard to follow written as it is. Without a `var` annotation, the identifier will be resolved "as a global". Since it (`arr1`) is not previously assigned it will result in a `ReferenceError` here if the first branch is never reached. Search for `[javascript] var hoist` for lots of related questions.

Comment: (Remove the `<div id="one" ..>` element to see the `ReferenceError`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that depends. Since you are passing the values to `gotIt` directly, it doesn't look like you need them globally so should have `var` on all of them.

That said, your code is quite messy and a little redundant. Try this:

```
function ArrValues(arr) {
    var arr1 = arr=='one' || arr=='all' ? ['grapes','peaches','plums'] : [],
        arr2 = arr=='two' || arr=='all' ? ['car','motorcycle','tree'] : [],
        arr3 = arr=='three' || arr=='all' ? ['200','1000','350'] : [];
    gotIt(arr1,arr2,arr3);
}
```

Note that I've given each one a default value of an empty array, otherwise you would end up with undefined variables.

Comment: A case statement would be clearer and remove the `all` redundancy.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. That looks a lot cleaner than mine Kolink.  A case statement sounded good, but if i have a large number of arrays wouldnt their order would be harder to change as I added new arrays.