# javascript arrays and closures

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Earlier I posted a question about accessing array values stored in functions,
  [passing array value using closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212604/passing-array-value-using-closure/15212675#15212675), and was told that this code would would do the job.

```
<script>
    function ArrValues(arr) {
     var arr1 = arr=='one' || arr=='all' ? ['grapes','peaches','plums'] : [],
     arr2 = arr=='two' || arr=='all' ? ['car','motorcycle','tree'] : [],
     arr3 = arr=='three' || arr=='all' ? ['200','1000','350'] : [];
     gotIt(arr1,arr2,arr3);
  }

 function gotIt(arr1,arr2,arr3){
    alert(arr1);
    alert(arr2);
    alert(arr3);
  }
</script>
```

I've updated the code as shown below. Would this be a good method of returning only the array I want without sending it as an argument to another function?

```
  <script>
  function ArrValues(arr) {
  var arr1 = arr=='one' || arr=='all' ? ['grapes','peaches','plums'] : [];
  if(arr1.length>0){
    return arr1;
  };

  arr2 = arr=='two' || arr=='all' ? ['car','motorcycle','tree'] : [];
  if(arr2.length>0){
    return arr2;
  };

 arr3 = arr=='three' || arr=='all' ? ['200','1000','350'] : [];
  if(arr3.length>0){
    return arr3;
   }
  }
 </script>

 <div id="one" onclick="ArrValues(this.id)">one</div>
 <div id="two" onclick="ArrValues(this.id)">two</div>
 <div id="three"onclick="ArrValues(this.id)">three</div>
 <div id="all"onclick="ArrValues(this.id)">all</div>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but important: in the code they suggested, every variable is declared locally, but on your new version you only declare `arr1`, making the other two global. You should add `var` before `arr2` and `arr3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. Since you're not interested in the "else" case, you would be better off with this:

```
if( arr == "one" || arr == "all") return ['grapes','peaches','plums'];
```

And similar constructs.

That being said, if you do this then the so-called "all" button will only ever return the "one" array, because it will always match the first `if` statement and return the array.

Comment: If you are not using an `"all"` button anymore, you can remove the `|| arr == "all"` from the `if` conditions.

Comment: Wait, I spoke too soon.  If I do need to get them all would I be forced to send values as paramaters, or run the function through a loop.

Comment: I really have no idea. I can't make sense of what you're trying to do, and it confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
function ArrValues(arr) {
    var values = {
         'one': ['grapes','peaches','plums'],
         'two': ['car','motorcycle','tree'],
         'three': ['200','1000','350']
        };

    return values[arr];
}
```

(*it does not handle the `all` case as you do not describe what to return in this case..*)

---

if with `all` you want all values merged in a single array then

```
function ArrValues(arr) {
    var match,
        values = {
            'one': ['grapes','peaches','plums'],
            'two': ['car','motorcycle','tree'],
            'three': ['200','1000','350']
        };

     if (arr!=='all'){
         match = values[arr];
     } else {
         match = values['one'].concat( values['two'] ).concat( values['three'] );
     }

     return match;
}
```