# Processing array values via closures

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

Sorry about the confusion in the last question.  I have been searching for a fast way to grab and update hundreds of array values stored in a closure function.  I have stayed away from using objects due to the belief that closures were faster, which I hear may not even be true.  I am not passing the variables via an onclick.  The performance of the two functions are all I am concerned with.  I am simply trying to update an array index, return the array values after updates, return the original array, return an empty array.

```
    <script>

function ArrValues(arr){
    if(arr=='ID') return ['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5'];
    if(arr=='NAM') return ['cat','dog','fish','bird','horse'];
    if(arr=='COL') return ['blue','yellow','green','pink','green'];
}

function IDUfunc(value,index,action) {
    var arr="ID";
    var IDU=ArrValues(arr);

       return function(value,index,action) {
        if(action==1){}
        if(action==2){IDU[index]=value;}
        if(action==3){IDU=ArrValues(arr);}
        if(action==4){IDU=['empty'];}

        return IDU;
    }
} 
IDU=IDUfunc(0,0,0);

  </script>

  <div onclick="alert(IDU(3,3,4))">test</div>
```

values in onclick represent array value, array index, and action to perform.  (sorry for any confusion).

Comment: wow, umm, like what are you _actually_ trying to achieve here?  I mean end result, not this rather odd (and contrived) looking code.

Comment: I'm trying to deliver hundreds of values to the user without db request.  Values are stored in arrays that can be updated, changed, and then uploaded.

Comment: please, do yourself a favour and learn knockoutjs or similar, it's very easy for this sort of thing.

Comment: For ArrValues, I'd used what was suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15238263/825789). About the performance, is this premature optimization, or are you experiencing real performance issues?

Comment: Pretty good so far in chrome, slow in IE8. Wondering if this is the right method for when I get up to over 2500 values.  I've moved away from tables and want the best performance possible for working with arrays.  Sorry about my style.  I was more of a spreasheets type of guy before I started using Javascript.